# How to create a custom tab in My account section and display recently added products when clicked?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I added a new tab in my account section, when I clicked on that tab I want to display recently added products. How will I be able to do it?

I added a new tab by adding some code in **customer.xml**

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>offer_product</name>
                <path>user/index/index</path>
                <label>My Offer Product</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

When I click on my offer product, I want to display recently added products along with all the tabs(i.e My Account must also get displayed) as given below:

[image]

The given below code is my **indexcontroller**:

```
<?php
class Test_User_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/account_dashboard')
        );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Account'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you layout xml

```
<user_index_index>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>

        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_test" template="test/test.phtml"
                />          
        </reference>
       </user_index_index>
```

in your test.phtml

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product") 
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
                            ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
                            ->setPageSize(10); //set page size as your wish
  foreach($products as $product):
     echo $product->getName();
      echo $product->getSku(); ?>
   <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()); ?>
    <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200); ?>">
   <?php
     // and so on
  endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working, Can you please explain me more how will I display the product inside the loop?

Comment: @Birju added the code..

Comment: @ Qaisar Satti and to display image of product?

Comment: @Birju added the code..

Comment: Thank U very much Qaisar. It helped me a lot